# Plugin to allow visitor to choose location (or area) and set persistent cookie

Tags: wordpress, cookies, plugins

I'm designing a site for a company with multiple locations. I want someone to be able to visit www.company.com/nashville and then set a cookie to make the local phone number appear in our nav bar or header across the rest of the site, even when they visit www.company.com/services, etc.

The functionality I'm trying to copy is similar to what's found here: http://www.whymonster.com/lehigh-valley

On that site, the phone number in the header will persist as the Lehigh Valley number until you intentionally go to a different location. If I were to visit http://www.whymonster.com/southbay/ the phone # would change and persist.

Thanks to anyone that can help.

Comment: please add code here for more details

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, there's no code here that I know of, that's why I was wondering if there's a plugin for it.